# Adjust code to have program run with Xamarin Live Android

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm supposed to edit this program on Visual Studio to display paragraphs from my favorite book. I already have that down, so my problem lies with deploying it using Xamarin Live. None of my computers are able to run Android Emulators, so Xamarin Live is the only way I can deploy android apps on. Yet for some reason when I try to use it on this program, the app just crashes. I tried testing the app again on a different program and it worked fine there, so it isn't the app that's the problem. So my question is which file do I need to edit to make my app compatible with Xamarin Live Android.
https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-book-samples/tree/master/Chapter04/BlackCat/BlackCat

Comment: Xamarin Live Player is not intended to be a full fledged emulator for testing.

Comment: Connect your Android device via USB and deploy/debug w/o Xamarin Live Player

Comment: what is the exception that it crashes with? Where is the exception stacktrace?